# Identify profile-icc with Image Magick

Tags: imagemagick, identify

Is there a way to return image profile with image magick command `identify` or some other command?

For example I have an image kitchen.jpg. This image has profile Euroscale Coated v2. I can see that by running `identify -verbose kitchen.jpg`.

```
...
  signature: ff8c7f0b6159ca8b63507c0a0eac0af64d639b19e871e13163fb53746a4c4ddd
  xapMM:DerivedFrom: 
Profiles:
  Profile-exif: 4869 bytes
  Profile-icc: 557164 bytes
    Euroscale Coated v2
  Profile-iptc: 7 bytes
    unknown[2,0]: 
  Profile-xmp: 7501 bytes
Artifacts:
  verbose: true
...
```

I tried `identify -verbose wohnbereih_original.tif | grep 'Profile-icc'` and it returns `Profile-icc: 557164 bytes` but than I don't now how to return next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
identify -verbose wohnbereih_original.tif | grep -A 2 'Profile-icc'
```

Comment: Thank you keepitreall89. I ended up using `identify -verbose wohnbereih_original.tif | grep -A 1 'Profile-icc' | grep -v Profile-icc | sed 's/^ *//'` to get name Profile-ICC profile. Your anwser helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try This

**identify -format %[profile:icc] wohnbereih_original.tif**

Comment: I get `identify: unknown image property "%[profile:icc]" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3875.` when trying this.

Comment: @rogach I get this too, but I also get a result (which has no line feed, so comes before the next command prompt) with something like Adobe RGB (1998)

Answer (score 1):

I did my research how to detect / identify ICC profile with imagemagick and reached this question.

Then, I found out

```
identify -format %[profile:icc] wohnbereih_original.tif
```

will available in imagemagick since version 6.8.7.2 (ref: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=24385 
and http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=24286)

For previous versions,

```
identify -verbose wohnbereih_original.tif | grep -A 2 'Profile-icc'
```

is a lifesaver.